# Quasar Framework - How to conditionally change class based on orientation

Tags: vuejs2, orientation, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar Framework VueJs.
In the below code snippen, i want to change the class from 'row' to 'column' based on orientation.

```
<div class="row">
  <div>First column</div>
  <div>Second column</div>
  <div>Third column</div>
</div>
```

something like this

```
:class="orientation==='portrait'?column:row"
```

But I am not able to find the right code snipped to get this. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working with <q-resize-observer @resize="onResize" />
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/resize-observer

Answer (score 0):

:class="orientation==='portrait'? 'column':'row'"
You need to have single quote with column and row as well

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
window.screen.orientation
```

o

```
if (orientation === "landscape-primary") {
  console.log("That looks good.");
} else if (orientation === "landscape-secondary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... the screen is upside down!");
} else if (orientation === "portrait-secondary" || orientation === "portrait-primary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... you should rotate your device to landscape");
} else if (orientation === undefined) {
  console.log("The orientation API isn't supported in this browser :(");
}
```

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation)